# What are the legal consequences if caught violating the COVID-19 Metro Manila curfew from 2020-03-15 to 2020-04-14?

Tags: philippines

What are the legal consequences if caught violating the [COVID-19 Metro Manila curfew from 2020-03-15 to 2020-04-14](https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/1241807/curfew-hours-for-metro-manila-lockdown-malls-establishments-to-be-shuttered)?

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks I was hoping for a reference to an official text of law.

Comment: It isn't clear to me if an actual law has been created yet, or if this is just an announcement by the relevant officials that they intend to create such a law.  If the latter then the precise details may not even have been worked out yet. I saw other sources that seemed to say that some aspects of the curfew needed approval by the President, which had not yet been granted.